# What is the best way to learn Touch Typing?

Tags: keyboard, performance, dvorak

#### Duplicate

> [How do I improve my Typing Skills?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410880/how-do-i-improve-my-typing-skills).**

I tried the test on http://speedtest.10-fast-fingers.com/. I reach only:

> `You type 337 characters per minute You`
> `have 58 correct words and you have 1`
> `wrong words`

How can I improve my typing speed? What free resources do you know of?

Should I learn the Dvorak Keyboard?

[image]

Comment: More answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94101/how-to-type-faster

Comment: Link provided from which this is supposedly a duplicate is non-existent.

Comment: For learning of touch typing on qwerty I recommend http://touchtyping.guru where an algorithm helps you to learn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Practice is the best way to get faster. I've found [TypeRacer](http://play.typeracer.com/) to be a fun and easily accessible game. Using it I quickly got from around 55 words per minute to over 70.

Comment: yes, it's really fun and addictive sometimes :)

Answer (score 6):

I removed all of the key caps from my IBM Model-M. Since I can't see the letters, I was forced to learn their positions and type without looking at the keys other than to initially orient my hands. When you're not able to take shortcuts, you tend to learn very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

[Mario](http://www.abandonia.com/en/games/987/Mario+Teaches+Typing.html) taught me.

Comment: Whoa, totally forgot about this. Brings back memories.

Answer (score 1):

I also took the test and reached 371 characters with one mistake. However, for programming, I would not see this as a bad result. I'm more worried about how to use tools like Intellisense and code templates better to speed up my coding. The [jedi coding](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/documentation.html) demo shows that you can get much higher gains that way than by doubling your typing speed.

Answer (score 0):

No need to learn Dvorak [according to XKCD](http://xkcd.com/561/) (and [more here](http://blag.xkcd.com/2009/03/27/a-brief-pair-of-notes/)).

I also remember reading in [The Design of Everyday Thing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385267746)s that QWERTY actually does quite a good job or spreading the commonly used letters across your fingers and whilst the Dvorak keyboard is a little better than QWERTY the benefits aren't significant enough to justify making the change.  (If I can find my copy I'll try and put up an exact quote.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to learn Dvorak. I can type 600+ Chars/minute on a querty pad, no problem.

The key is: Repetition, repetition, repetition.
What you're doing while you learn typing is creating new 'highways' straight form your brain's spelling center through your spine to your fingers.

Hence, a good typist will spell a word in his mind, and his fingers 'automatically' type those characters because there's a 10 lane highway from his brain to his fingers. In your case, it's a modest 3 lane highway.

Practice, practice, practice.
Good training for if you already know how to type : [www.play4traffic.com](http://www.play4traffic.com)

There's also loads of typing tutor programs available online, but the key is repetition and persistance.

My native language is Dutch, so in english it's not as good. I tried the test you gave:

```
317 points, so you achieved position 194065 of 2927935 on the ranking list    

You type 476 characters per minute
You have 80 correct words and you have 4 wrong words
```

Comment: Dammit you are fast! ;)

I've never learned to write with 10 fingers. It's more an automatism which I can't get rid of. My own 2handed typing system has developed itself over the last 5 years. Maybe your faster because you haven't to write German text.

Answer (score 0):

As with all things: practice makes perfect. Making posts on StackOverflow is a start :)

Unless if you want to win typing contests, a Qwerty or Azerty keyboard will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why?

Why do you want to type more quickly? I seldom find that my fingers or typing speed are the issue when it comes to software development. Sure I have a fair speed, but programming is about ***SO*** much more than typing speed. I've been using a QUERTY keyboard since about 1983 so I guess repetition helps.

But learning to hold back on typing and thinking about what it is you're about to do is far more valuable IMHO.

Having said that, I would expect any developer to be able to type reasonably quickly using most fingers, or at least more than their two index fingers ;)

Comment: Nice to know! But I'll learn it for German/English language, not programming. Maybe software developers should learn a absolut different Style? You're right, Programming isn't typing speed related. 

I talk a lot on MSN/IRC/ICQ, so fast writing may be very good.

Answer (score 0):

This game taught me a few years back.

[The Typing Of The Dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Typing_of_the_Dead)

I can now type fairly quickly without looking at the keyboard.  You need to learn to use the correct hand position. Then you must have good discipline and only use the correct finger to type the correct letters.  I even went so far as to delete correct chars typed with the wrong finger.

It takes time, and you will almost definitely go slower before you go faster, but it is worth it.